# Converting numbers in linear space to binary using sigmoid in R

Tags: r, supervised-learning, topic-models

I'm running a binary prediction using a supervised topic modeling package in R (`lda` package, using `slda.predict` function). The result of the prediction returns results in linear space. From Googling around, people say that I need to take a sigmoid  to convert the result to a logical value. I'm not really sure what this means.

Basically I have list of documents, and their corresponding labels. What I am trying to do is set 80% of these documents and their labels, and train them using supervised LDA. The label of the document is 0 or 1. I manage to train the document just fine using this piece of code:

```
example <- c("I am the role model","I have a major crazy   headache","i don't have money", "you are money crazy major")
corpus = lexicalize(example, lower=TRUE)
label = c(1,1,0,0)
params <- sample(c(1, 0), 2, replace=TRUE)
result <- slda.em(documents=corpus$documents,
              K=2,
              vocab=poliblog.vocab,
              num.e.iterations=10,
              num.m.iterations=4,
              alpha=1.0, eta=0.1,
              label,
              params,
              variance=0.25,
              lambda=1.0,
              logistic=TRUE,
              method="sLDA")
```

for simplicity purpose, i'll try to predict the same document given the model above.

```
predictions <- slda.predict(corpus$documents,
                            result$topics, 
                        result$model,
                        alpha = 1.0,
                        eta=0.1)
```

Now, my problem is, the result of the prediction isn't binary. it's continuous value. I need to convert it back to binary using some sort of sigmoid(according to an [article here](https://lists.cs.princeton.edu/pipermail/topic-models/2012-June/001912.html))

The result i'm getting doesn't seem like a probability. For the 4 documents above, this is the output of the predictions variable

```
           [,1]
[1,]  44.827420
[2,]  53.895682
[3,] -17.139034
[4,]   1.299764
```

How do I do this in R?

Comment: this is the post that describe what i am asking. https://lists.cs.princeton.edu/pipermail/topic-models/2012-June/001912.html

Comment: I suspect this is really a conceptual issue masquerading as an R question, but it needs clarifying to be answerable.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, your model & your goals here? Can you re-phrase your question in a software-neutral way? Can you include the code you used (someone might provide some R-specific help as a bonus)?

Comment: I suspect the result you are getting back is a probability, and that is more useful than a 1 or 0. But you'd need to provide a lot more detail for anyone to know if this is correct.

Comment: the result is not probability. a sample output is given above

Comment: I voted to reopen because some searching of the usual sources (e.g., rseek) comes up only with awful documentation.  Although one might guess that the predictions are log odds, that's not certain; and without looking at the source code it might be difficult to come up with a correct interpretation.